# How to preserve line breaks when storing command output to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, line-breaks

I’m using bash shell on Linux.  I have this simple script …

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMP=`sed -n '/'"Starting deployment of"'/,/'"Failed to start context"'/p' "/usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log" | tac | awk '/'"Starting deployment of"'/ {print;exit} 1' | tac`
echo $TEMP
```

However, when I run this script

```
./temp.sh
```

all the output is printed without the carriage returns/new lines.  Not sure if its the way I’m storing the output to $TEMP, or the echo command itself.

How do I store the output of the command to a variable and preserve the line breaks/carriage returns?

Comment: They're preserved in the variable just fine (except for the last one); it's your echo that's broken. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls entry #14

Comment: also, `don't` store `commands` in `variables`. `Use` a `function` instead

Answer (score 513, accepted):

With shell scripting, one needs to always **quote** variables, especially when working with strings.

Here is an example of the problem:

*Example variable:*

```
$ f="fafafda
> adffd
> adfadf
> adfafd
> afd"
```

**Output without quoting the variable:**

```
$ echo $f
fafafda adffd adfadf adfafd afd
```

**Output WITH quoting the variable:**

```
$ echo "$f"
fafafda
adffd
adfadf
adfafd
afd
```

*Explaination:*

Without quotes, the shell replaces `$TEMP` with the characters it contains (one of which is a newline). Then, before invoking `echo` shell splits that string into multiple arguments using the `Internal Field Separator` (IFS), and passes that resulting list of arguments to `echo`. By default, the `IFS` is set to whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines), so the shell chops your `$TEMP` string into arguments and it never gets to see the newline, because the shell considers it a separator, just like a space.

Comment: `xdotool type  "$myVar"` doesn't work. it's still typing the content of the variable without new lines

Comment: What if you want to do something like `FOO="$(echo $VAR)"`; how do you quote `$VAR` properly when it's already inside quotes?

Comment: @weberc2 You simply quote it again: `"$(echo "$VAR")"`. Yes, it's odd to parse, but apparently easier for shells than for us.

Answer (score 11):

I have ran into the same problem, a quote will help

```
ubuntu@host:~/apps$ apps="abc
> def"
ubuntu@host:~/apps$ echo $apps
abc def
ubuntu@host:~/apps$ echo "$apps"
abc
def
```

Comment: Answering a question almost 5 years later without adding any new details to the previous answer(s) or providing a new solution is not a good idea; please avoid posting these kinds of answers.

Comment: Loving the precision of your "almost 5 years", @MAChitgarha, :)