# Shell Script store cat output in a variable

Tags: sh, cat

I have an AWS access file which contains 2 lines.

I'm trying to save its content into a variable, but it always store only the last line..

```
accessKeyFile=$(cat "$awsAccessKeyPath");
echo $accessKeyFile;
```

How can I store the whole file content in the variable?

Comment: your solution looks ok, except that you might really want `echo "$var"`. Has your keyFile passed thru MS Windows? if so, fix the line endings with `dos2unix "$awsAccessKeyPath"`. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I preserve line breaks when storing a command output to a variable in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101778/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-storing-a-command-output-to-a-variable-in-bas)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat file.txt); do
    accessKeyFile=$(echo $i)
    echo $accessKeyFile

done
```

So you can save whole lines into accessKeyFile