# Bash: find and path

Tags: bash

As an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709021/bash-recursively-write-a-line-to-a-file-from-column-maximum?noredirect=1&lq=1) , I would now like to have not only the filename, but the directories up to k positions back. Here's the problem:

I have directories named `RUN1`, `RUN2`, and `RUN3`
Each directory has some files. Directory `RUN1` has files `mod1_1.csv`, `mod1_2.csv`, `mod1_3.csv`. Directory `RUN2` has files `mod2_1.csv`, `mod2_2.csv`, `mod3_3.csv`, etc.

The contents of `mod1_1.csv` file look like this:

```
5.71 6.66 5.52 6.90
5.78 6.69 5.55 6.98
5.77 6.63 5.73 6.91
```

And `mod1_2.csv` looks like this:

```
5.73 6.43 5.76 6.57
5.79 6.20 5.10 7.01
5.71 6.21 5.34 6.81
```

In RUN2, mod2_1.csv looks like this:

```
5.72 6.29 5.39 5.59
5.71 6.10 5.10 7.34
5.70 6.23 5.23 6.45
```

And mod2_2.csv looks like this:

```
5.72 6.29 5.39 5.69
5.71 6.10 5.10 7.32
5.70 6.23 5.23 6.21
```

My goal is to obtain the line with the smallest value of column 4 for each RUN* directory, and write that and the model which gave it and part of the path to a new .csv file. Right now, I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
resultfile="best_results_mlp_onelayer.txt"
for d in $(find . -type d -name 'RUN*' | sort);
do
 find "$d" -type f -name 'mod*' -exec awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' {} \;|sort -k4 -g |head -1 >> "$resultfile"
done
```

This gives me:

```
5.73 6.43 5.76 6.57 ./RUN_1/mod1_2.csv
5.72 6.29 5.39 5.59 ./RUN_2/mod2_1.csv
```

But I would like a .csv file with these contents:

```
5.73 6.43 5.76 6.57 ./DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/RUN_1/mod1_2.csv
5.72 6.29 5.39 5.59 ./DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/RUN_2/mod2_1.csv
```

where my pwd is `/DIRk/DIRm/DIRl/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3`

EDIT:

Based on a reply, what I mean by 'k positions back' is:

Right now, my code gives me `./RUN_1/mod1_2.csv` as the last column value in the first row. To me, that is a pwd 'one position back', because it shows the directory where the file `mod1_2.csv` is located. I would like the path '4 positions back'. That is, I would like `./DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/RUN_1/mod1_2.csv`. I said 'k' because that's a common placeholder, and I was hoping I could just substitute a number in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my answer in your previous question:

`find` passes the file with the path under which it was found. So if you search in `"/path/to/$d"`, you will get `"/path/to/$d/filename.csv"`. Just make `find` search in the path you would like to get.

So if your `RUN*` dirs are located in `/path/to/`, and you would like to have `./to/RUNx/filename.csv` in your results, you can always do

```
cd /path/ && find ./to/RUNx/ # ...
```

If you need the absolute path, you can just run `find` on `/path/to/RUNx`

*Just be careful when changing directories, and make sure to change back to where you have to if necessary. (eg. You might have to provide the path to your output file)*

Comment: What solved this was actually a combination of your answers. I'll post it as a separate answer below. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Following dgeorgiev's answer, I placed my results gathering code in a directory further up in the hierarchy. So, continuing from my question, if my `pwd` is `/DIRk/DIRm/DIRl/DIR1/DIR2/DIR3`, I moved my .sh file to `DIRk/DIRm/DIRl`. Then I ran this:

```
#!/bin/bash
resultfile="best_results_mlp.txt"

for d in $(find . -type d -name 'RUN*' | sort);
do
   find "$d" -type f -name 'mod*' -exec awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' {} \;|sort -k4 -g |head -1 >> "$resultfile"

done
```

And the result was, as desired:

```
5.73 6.43 5.76 6.57 ./DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/RUN_1/mod1_2.csv
5.72 6.29 5.39 5.59 ./DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/RUN_2/mod2_1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any commas in these CSVs. I assume you're just separating by whitespace.  And since you're already using awk in your `find` line, I guess we can assume that you're open to awk-based options.

```
$ find . -type f
./RUN1/mod1_1
./RUN1/mod1_2
./RUN2/mod2_1
./RUN2/mod2_2
$ awk 'NR == 1 {n=$4} $4 > n {n=$4; f=FILENAME} END {print f,n}' RUN*/mod*
RUN2/mod2_1 7.34
```

This uses the awk built-in variable `FILENAME` which always contains the name of the current file.

I can't tell from your question what you mean by "k positions back", but you can strip or parse this output however you see fit.

Comment: Thank you @ghoti, but how could I integrate this into what I already have?

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this

```
find . -type d -name 'RUN*' | while read -r dir; do
    awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' "$dir"/mod* \
    | sort -k4 -g | head -1
done
```

(sorry about my original misinterpretation of your requirements, edited to correct the issue)

Comment: Thank you @jil, but that does not solve the problem. I still need the directories.