# Save output of bash command for use with pipe command (|)

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have the following problem

- Count the files in the folder which have an "a" in the filename
- Repeat for "e", "i" and all the other vowels

One solution is:

```
FilesWithA=$(ls | grep a | wc -l)
FilesWithE=$(ls | grep e | wc -l)
FilesWithI=$(ls | grep i | wc -l)
FilesWithO=$(ls | grep o | wc -l)
FilesWithU=$(ls | grep u | wc -l)
```

This works fine, but the folder contains many thousands of files. I'm looking to speed this up by capturing the output of `ls` in a variable, then sending the output to `grep` and `wc`, but the syntax is defeating me.

```
lsCaptured=$(ls)
FilesWithA=$($lsCaptured | grep a | wc -l) #not working!
```

Comment: `grep a <<<“$lsCaptured”`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable), or [How to preserve line breaks when storing a command output to a variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101778/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-storing-a-command-output-to-a-variable-in-bash)

Comment: @oguzismail: None of those gave the `<<<` or `here-string` operator, which worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
#!/bin/bash

captured="$(printf '%s\n' *)"
filesWithA=$(grep -c a <<< "$captured")
```

### Notes :

- `<<<` is a *here-string*
- please, thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: grep has the `-c` option for counting -- no need for `wc`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just what I needed. The answers suggested in a comment were not helpful. Note that you can insert the `here-string` even in more complex commands such as `FilesWithA=$(grep a <<< "$captured" | wc -l)`.