# egrep returning matches separated by string

Tags: macos, grep

I'm trying to extract specific lines from the output of a command that outputs a lot of lines of text. I've hit a bit of a wall at this point:

```
pathsText=$(system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | egrep '^\s+Location:\s+.*$')
```

This extracts the correct lines, but it puts them all into a single long line, with matches separated by spaces rather than newlines.

In other words, I'm expecting something like this:

```
  Location: /a/b
  Location: /c/d/e
  ...
```

And that's what I get if I run that same egrep command against a text file containing the output of system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType in the Terminal. But the command above does not put that into pathsText. Instead, it's giving me:

```
Location: /a/b Location: /c/d/e ...
```

Unfortunately, I can't just split based on spaces, because the paths contained in each line may contain spaces.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is unclear how you checked "Instead, it's giving me.....". After reading this question I was unable to reproduce something that seems to be a problem.....

Comment: @Luuk Using echo to display $pathsText results in something with no line breaks. I know this isn't a problem with echo, however, because if I echo the results of system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType directly, the line breaks are present. Piping to egrep seems to cause them to be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not reproducable:

```
luuk@mini ~ % pathsText=$(system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | egrep '^\s+Location:\s+.*$')
luuk@mini ~ % echo $pathsText 
      Location: /System/Applications/System Preferences.app
      Location: /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
      Location: /System/Applications/TV.app
      Location: /System/Applications/FaceTime.app
      Location: /System/Applications/TextEdit.app
      Location: /System/Applications/Time Machine.app
      Location: /System/Applications/App Store.app
      Location: /System/Library/ColorSync/Calibrators/Display Calibrator.app
      Location: /System/Library/CoreServices/P.....
```

EDIT:

The answer is here:

https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+assign+variable+looses+carriage+return+of+line+feed

finding a link on stackoverflow.com to:

[How to preserve line breaks when storing command output to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101778/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-storing-command-output-to-a-variable)

Comment: Please try putting this in a shell script and running it, rather than doing it directly from the command line. Within a shell script, it gives me different results.

Comment: The edit solved it, thanks!